# Event when dragging item out of menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, dom-events, packery

I have a menu of images that I can drag out of the list and will snap back in place using [packery](https://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html)

```
<div id="menu">
        <div class="img">
               <Img src="..."/>
        </div>
```

I would like to know when one of the the images is dragged outside of the list. 
I tried a lot of MouseEvent Listeners but  because the image stays under my mouse I never really leave the div.

At the moment I use the position of the cursor and compare it relatively to the border of the menu but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to accomplish this in native JS or jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SortableJS](https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/) library. Supported by: Vue, React, Angular, Knockout, Meteor, Polymer, Ember, and other.

Comment: I actually looked into this framework. This framework completely misses the option of auto rearranging tile based lists.  I would need to animate the snap back myself and it also doesn't solve the original problem "How can my js notice the object going outside my list div"